# How to only format Python in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I am trying to create some settings to auto lint and format Python files when saving. I have the settings I desire for Python but when editing other files such as XML, VSCode will automatically format them as well. Is there a way I can get VSCode to only format the Python files?

Here are my settings for formatting and linting:

```json
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--max-line-length=240",
    "--disable=C0111,unused-import"
],
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "line-length", "250"
],
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
},
```

Comment: Approach the problem in a different way: how to _disable_ VS Code's automatic formatting for XML files. Since you have `"editor.formatOnSave": true`, VS Code will use its available formatters (built-in + installed extensions) to auto-format your XML files. It's not about your Python settings, and it's probably more confusing approaching it from preventing the Python formatter to affect other files.

Comment: Do you have any formatter extensions installed? Particularly for XML files?

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks! I have this xml formatter extension installed: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml

Comment: Then that's probably the one formatting your XML files, not the Python one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this, it works for me prevent my SQL files from being formated.

Credit to the original post [here](https://dev.to/adamlombard/how-to-use-the-black-python-code-formatter-in-vscode-3lo0).

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
},
```

Comment: This is what I ended up with for anyone interested.

"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
 "--max-line-length=240",
 "--disable=F0401,unused-import,"
],
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
 "line-length", "250"
],
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"[python]": {
 "editor.formatOnSave": true,
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": true
 },
},
"[javascript]": {
 "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
 "editor.formatOnSave": true,
},